# Windows 11 almost 6 gigabytes of system memory are hidden and not available

Tags: memory, windows-11, task-manager, memory-management

I'm using the latest version of the Windows 11 and I'm curious where almost 6 gigabytes of the system RAM memory disappear. I have 32 Gigs of RAM installed in the system. According to the task manager, 44% percent of the system memory is in use (which is 14.5 Gigs), however as I can see, real windows processes are using less than 9 Gigs, the question is - where the other 6 Gigs of the RAM memory allocated? The Windows system has hidden it somewhere for internal purposes or what? How is this possible to simply cut 6 Gigs of RAM?????
[image]

Comment: Windows 11 is 64-bit only = 4 GB +- and then things you are doing. Seems normal

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap

Comment: Also unhide hidden processes in task manager

Comment: Task Manager isn’t sufficient to diagnose this problem a tool like RAMMap will provide sufficient enough to diagnose the problem